# Set timeout always 10 seconds for remoteFunction

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, governorlimits, ajax

When the onLoad function is called this code runs. The timeout is set to 2 minutes but the server always returns an error after 10 seconds despite the timeout field. How can I set the timeout to be longer?

```
sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
sforce.connection.remoteFunction({
    url : '{!endpointUrl}',
    requestHeaders: {
        "Content-Type":"text/xml",
    },
    requestData: xmlBody ,
    method: "POST",
    onSuccess : function(response) {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response,"text/xml");
        var pdf = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Contents")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("PdfObject").src = "data:application/pdf;base64," + pdf;
    },
    onFailure : function(response) {
        alert("There was a problem. Please try refreshing the page or try again at another time. " + response);
    },
    async:true,
    timeout:120000
});
```

Comment: You can't raise the governor limit, you only get 10s for synchronous execution. See: [remote action function encountering CPU time out limit exception](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46931/remote-action-function-encountering-cpu-time-out-limit-exception)

Comment: Could I get around it by making it asynchronous? If so, how?

Comment: Nope. What are you doing that you need two minutes on the servers? That's crazy.

Comment: I'm requesting a base64 encoded pdf from an overburdened api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) (emphasis mine):

> ### Per-Transaction Apex Limits
>
> **Maximum CPU time on the Salesforce servers**<sup>5</sup>
> Synchronous Limit: 10,000 milliseconds
> Asynchronous Limit: 60,000 milliseconds
>
> <sup>5</sup> CPU time is calculated for all executions on the Salesforce application servers occurring in one Apex transaction. CPU time is calculated for the executing Apex code, and for any processes that are called from this code, such as package code and workflows. CPU time is private for a transaction and is isolated from other transactions. **Operations that don’t consume application server CPU time aren’t counted toward CPU time. For example, the portion of execution time spent in the database for DML, SOQL, and SOSL isn’t counted, *nor is waiting time for Apex callouts***.

All `@RemoteAction` calls are synchronous, so you cannot raise it above 10 seconds. Even if you could make the call asynchronously, you would only get 60 seconds, not 120.

In order to use asynchronous functionality, your best bet may be to use a `@future` method (which must be `void`, mind) and then just do all post-processing in that `Apex` method.

Comment: Thanks @adrian. I can't seem to find any instructions on how to make it asynchronous. (I thought I had done it by setting async to true)

Comment: If you want to parse the results of your method call, you cannot use async. You can use `@future`, `Queueable`, or `Batchable` depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Can any of that be done in javascript or only in the controller? Thanks again.

Comment: You can make http callouts via Javascript, but that is a topic more suitable to [so] as it is completely independent of Salesforce.

Comment: @Carson You can also use a [continuation method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_continuation_overview.htm), which lets you have the full time, if you want to callout from Apex Code.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Synchronous time doesn't include callout time on the server, so you could theoretically perform a callout that lasts close to two minutes using a RemoteAction.

Comment: It doesn't include waiting time, true.

Answer (score 0):

This [help topic](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176812&language=en_US) explains what's going on:

> AJAX API remoteFunction timeout parameter respected?
>
> Knowledge Article Number: 000176812
>
> Description: There is a method named remoteFunction in connection.js file which is used for AJAX calls.
>
> Details could be found at:
>   http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_ajax_queryresultiterator.htm#ajax_proxy
>
> What ever value is passed for the timeout parameter, the function has no effect.
>
> Is the timeout parameter in remoteFunction configurable?
>
> Resolution: No, the remoteFunction's timeout parameter is not configurable.
>
> When the conenction.js file is studied, we can see that the file does not have any handler for timeout argument.
>
> The remoteFunction can be called as (bold text represent the parameters):

```
sforce.connection.remoteFunction({
               url : "http://www.myExternalServer.com",
               onSuccess : function(response) {
                      alert("result" + response);
                  }
           });
```

> remoteFunction descritpion can be checked at:
>
> ../soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js
>
> As per instance:
>
> https://na1.salesforce.com/soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js
>
> https://ap1.salesforce.com/soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js
>
> https://cs1.salesforce.com/soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js
>
> The remoteFunction do not have any parameter handler for timeout argument.

---

You can, however, use a [@RemoteAction](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Summer13/Configurable+Timeout+for+JavaScript+Remote+Requests) and configure its timeout, use a [Continuation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_continuation_overview.htm) method, or use the [AJAX proxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_proxy.htm).